# ImageView getLocationtOnScreen android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get the coordinates of the image on the screen. I currently have an ImageView within an activity. I understand that the getLocationOnScreen() method can only be called once the layout has been created, so calling this method within the oncreate function would return [0,0]. But I do not know how to get this method to return the correct values. I have tried overiding various superclass methods, like the onstart method or the onTouchEvent method and it still returns [0,0] to me. The code I currently have is as follows:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    // Some code here after which ..
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageVfi);        
    image.setImageBitmap(imageData.entrySet().iterator().next().getValue());
}
```

Then I have the onStart method which I have overriden

```
@Override
public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();        
    image.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int[] dim = new int[2];
            image.getLocationOnScreen(dim);
            new AlertDialog.Builder(DisplayPicture.this)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setTitle("Touch coordinates : " +
                    String.valueOf(dim[0]) + "x" + String.valueOf(dim[1]))
            .setPositiveButton("OK", 
                     new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {   
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                 {
                     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 }
            }).show();
            // image calculations go here
            return true;

        }
    });
}
```

This returns 0X0 to me. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I would like to add that I think it is treating the whole screen as the image, because when I call the image.getHeight() function it returns 800 pixels and the image.getWidth function returns 480 pixels which is the same as the screen resolution. However, the actually visible image does not take up the whole screen. Any idea how I can fix this ?

Comment: Please note, the rest of the blank areas were not within the original image.

Comment: I just realised that I have been called the getLocationOnScreen method on the ImageView,whereas my image does not occupy the whole View. So this means that I will have to somehow map the screen coordinates to the actual image co-ordinates. I'm not sure how I can go about doing this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ImageView does not offer a way to get the location of its image on screen. You can only query the location of the ImageView itself. You can try to use ImageView.getImageMatrix() but I'm not sure we populate it when the image is simply centered (as opposed to scaled, etc.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was able to get the image co-ordinates using the getImageMatrix as suggested. I have added my solution below

Answer (score 3):

Solution after following advice given above

Solution:

Following the advice provided by Romain Guy below, I was able to get the co-ordinates but adding the following code to the onStart overidden method.

```
display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
            int orientation = display.getOrientation();
            float rowStart=0, rowEnd=0, columnStart=0, columnEnd=0;
            if(orientation ==0)
            {
                final Matrix matrix = image.getImageMatrix();
                float[] values = new float[9];
                matrix.getValues(values);
                rowStart = values[0];
                columnStart = values[5];
                rowEnd = image.getWidth()-rowStart;
                columnEnd = image.getHeight()-columnStart;
            }else if(orientation == 1)
            {
                final Matrix matrix = image.getImageMatrix();
                float[] values = new float[9];
                matrix.getValues(values);
                rowStart = values[2];
                columnStart = values[3];
                rowEnd = image.getWidth()-rowStart;
                columnEnd = image.getHeight()-columnStart;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's only the image view that you have in your activity, then it will be positioned by default in the top left corner with coordinates 0x0.

Comment: No, I have positioned it in the center by using android:scaleType="center", so the returned coordinates are not correct. I have a temporary fix which is to scale it to fit the screen but the image then loses its aspect ratio.

Comment: @k9ty try scaling the image with "fit center". Then you can get the image matrix and calculate the size of the image on the screen. From that you can get the coordinates = location of image view + ( the width or height of the image view / 2 - width or height of the image / 2 ). Whether you use width or height for the calculation depends on the aspect ratio of the screen and the image.