# Which position does "image.getLocationOnScreen" gives out?

Tags: android, function

I want to use this function `image.getLocationOnScreen` in android studio, to let me show the correct position of my `imageView`. But i have a question, which position gives the function out. The upper left corner, the upper right corner, the lower left corner or the lower right corner?

I don't know which position it is, I hope that one of you knows that.
Thanks for coming answers.

Comment: top margin(x) and leftmargin(y) ... the start point of the image... Think u have a square, android will return u the top left point of that square...

Comment: This [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5768291/imageview-getlocationtonscreen-android) might do the trick

Comment: Thanks for your responses. image.getLocationOnScreen turns out the top left corner. Thanks !